# Gdk.Screen.get_default() not working after PyInstaller

Tags: python, screen, x11, pyinstaller, gdk

Once again, I have a problem with PyInstaller-compiled executables not working the same way as python scripts do...

I need to read the system screen resolution in my program, so I've added this simple function for it:

```
# Get screen size for Linux
from gi.repository.Gdk import Screen 
def GetResolution():
    screenvar = Screen.get_default()
    width = screenvar.get_width()
    height = screenvar.get_height()
    return [width, height]
```

When launched with Python, it works perfectly.

However, an executable made with PyInstaller crashed. At first I thought it's a problem with library hooks - seen that before. That wasn't the case, though - the library and it's functions work, but it turns out "Screen.get_default()" returned NULL.

So this is the behaviour described in GDK documentation:

> gdk_screen_get_default ()
>
> Returns: a GdkScreen, or NULL if there is no default display.

For me it successfully returns the GdkScreen object when run with Python, but returns NULL in a PyInstaller executable.

So, why isn't the "default display" detected by this function in the executable, and how to make it work?

PS: I have a similar PyInstaller-made EXE working fine in Windows, but it uses a different library for reading the screen data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using alternative imports to get the screen info. Now my function looks like this:

```
# Get screen size for Linux
import gtk
def GetResolution():
    window = gtk.Window()
    screen = window.get_screen()
    width = gtk.gdk.screen_width()
    height = gtk.gdk.screen_height()
    return [width, height]
```

Works both in a python script and in a PyInstaller executable, tested on 32-bit and 64-bit Linux Mint 17.3.

Still don't know what caused the problem with the library I originally used.